# How to split a string in to letters in MATLAB?

Tags: string, matlab, split

I have a text and I want to turn it into an array of separated letters.
Eg.:

```
'hello world' → ['h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d']
```

thanks.

p.s. MATLAB 2013a

Comment: 'hello world' already is an array of separate letters...?

Comment: Please provide an example - where have you stored the text?

Comment: 'hello world' and ['h','e','l','l','o',' ','w','o','r','l','d'] are exactly the same thing. Its just two ways of writing but yield the same result.

Comment: `isequal('hello', ['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'])` returns `1`. What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In many ways the string 'hello world' is an array of separated letters. Maybe you are looking for a cell array where each element is a scalar character

```
x = mat2cell('hello world', 1, ones(11, 1))

x = 

    'h'    'e'    'l'    'l'    'o'    ' '    'w'    'o'    'r'    'l'    'd'
```

Comment: @ifryed works for what? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: I'd change it to `a = 'hello world'; x = mat2cell(string, 1, ones(numel(a), 1));` to make it more robust. And @Dan "why?" -> sometimes a minimal example makes no sense, but why not? Just imagine the string contains not letters, but numbers or binary numbers or flags or whatever. So you could need it in cells rather then a string.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Because it achieves nothing. There is nothing the OP can do with it, that couldn't be done before. So why waste time on the extra complexity?

Comment: @thewaywewalk if it's binary numbers then use `'10101' - '0'`, if it's a flag then what good would it do putting it in a cell. The reason I'm asking why is because there is almost definitely a better way to go about this

Comment: @thewaywewalk your version is potentially more robust, but it is also more complicated. In fact you define `a`, but then use `string`. Further, `numel` isn't really correct here since `a`/`string` has to be 1xN so `size(a, 2)` is better.

Comment: @Dan Sometimes cell arrays are useful. What about `plot(randn(11)); legend(x)`?

Comment: @DanielE.Shub or if `x` had been left as `'hello world'` then why not `legend(x(:))`?

Comment: @Dan because `legend` with strings is dangerous: `legend(x(:), 'Box', 'Off')` versus `legend(y, 'Box', 'Off')` where `x` is a character array and `y` is a cell array.

Answer (score 5):

Your original question does not make much sense; a string already is an array of characters.

Building on the assumption the others here have taken (that you want a cell array of individual characters), there is this slightly shorter alternative:

```
>> num2cell('hello world')
ans = 
   'h'    'e'    'l'    'l'    'o'    ' '    'w'    'o'    'r'    'l'    'd'
```

Another way:

```
>> regexp('hello world', '.', 'match')
ans = 
   'h'    'e'    'l'    'l'    'o'    ' '    'w'    'o'    'r'    'l'    'd'
```

You can also take a look at [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html) (introduced in R2013a or so)

`num2cell` preserves the class of the input argument, as seen in the relevant section in `num2cell`:

```
c = cell(size(a));
for i=1:numel(a)
    c{i} = a(i);
end
```

The basics: under the hood, a string (== array of `chars`) is essentially an array of 8-bit integers, interpreted a different way. Type `'hello world'+0` to see what I mean; you'll get the UTF-8 table values of the individual characters in an array of integers (well, `double`s, but oh well).

Comment: `num2cell` - same as `mat2cell` in this context, except you type much less.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I understand, a string is essentially an array of characters, so there's nothing to do:

```
>> str = 'hello world'
str = hello world
>> str(1)
ans = h
>> str(2)
ans = e
>> str(3)
ans = l
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? This is correct.